# SI and SIR model in R

Tags: r

i want test my approach using the **SI model** in **R**. and for that i use the **"EpiModel"** package. This package require some input like:

```
param <- param.dcm(inf.prob = 0.2, act.rate = 0.25)
init <- init.dcm(s.num = 500, i.num = 2)
control <- control.dcm(type = "SI", nsteps = 500)
```

where: **s.num** is the number of susceptible nodes, and **i.num** is the number of infected nodes.

i have an algorithm that give the best influentials of a network.

My question is: can i identify those influential nodes in the **init.dcm** parameter instead of giving just the number of influentials. i means that for example i have nodes **1** and node **34** are the influentials (infected). so how can i identify those nodes in the **i.num** paratemer instead of telling just that the **i.num=2**.?

thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, although I'm interested in learning epidemic models in general. I had a quick look, and see that in the *network* models, you can do it. The `init.net` function has a `status.vector` parameter. Let me know if it helps you.